# Retrieve customer who bought more than 13 different products who never purchased same product

Tags: mysql, sql-server, adventureworks

I tried this. But I feel this gives people who ordered same product

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(od.orderqty) OrderQty, 
                c.customerid, 
                od.productid 
FROM   sales.customer c 
       INNER JOIN sales.salesorderheader oh 
               ON c.customerid = oh.customerid 
       INNER JOIN sales.salesorderdetail od 
               ON oh.salesorderid = od.salesorderid 
GROUP  BY od.productid, 
          c.customerid 
HAVING Count(od.productid) > 10 
ORDER  BY c.customerid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what flavor of SQL you're using but try this:

```
select  t.CustomerID
from    (
select  c.CustomerID
        , count(distinct od.ProductID) as DistinctCount
        , count(od.ProductID) as Count
from    Sales.Customer c
join    Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh
        on c.customerid = oh.customerid
join    Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
        on oh.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID
group 
by      c.CustomerID 
) as t
where   t.DistinctCount = t.Count
and     t.DistinctCount > 13
order 
by      t.CustomerID
```

Comment: you should add `t.DistinctCount>13` to filter customers who bought more than 13 different products

Comment: @AB_87 Good looking out! Thanks!